# XSLT to remove duplicates completely

Tags: xslt

I know there are solutions plenty to remove duplicates, but this one is slightly different. I need to remove the element from the output if it is a duplicate. 
Input:

```
<SanctionList>
    <row>
        <PersonId>1000628</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1000634</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1113918</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1133507</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1113918</PersonId>
    </row>
</SanctionList>
```

Output expected:

```
<SanctionList>
    <row>
        <PersonId>1000628</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1000634</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1133507</PersonId>
    </row>
</SanctionList>
```

Here is what I tried but the parser returns  1 for each of the groups. Shouldnt it return 2 for PersonId 1113918 since it appears twice in the list?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SanctionList">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="PersonId">
            <xsl:text> Count for </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                <xsl:text> is </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks kindly!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note we are not a code-writing service but a volunteer group of programmers here to help troubleshoot earnest efforts. Look into [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for XSLT 1.0 or [for-each-group](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/for-each-group.html) in XSLT 2.0 to count distinct values and remove any grouped value greater than 1.

Comment: Thanks Parfait.. I used your direction and looked up for-each-group. Im still a noob when it comes to xslt, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As mentioned, `for-each-group` works in XSLT 2.0, not XSLT 1.0. Does your processor accommodate 2.0?

Comment: I using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.5 in the OxygenXML Editor. That supports xslt 2.0

Comment: Perfect! Thanks... Could you briefly explain the [2] in the last line of the code? What does that signify?

Comment: @JeromeHillman, The meaning of `[2]` is specified in the provided explanation in the answer -- more specifically in steps 3 and 4. Please, ask if you have any other questions -- I will be glad to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there are solutions plenty to remove duplicates, but this one
>   is slightly different. I need to remove the element from the output if
>   it is a duplicate

**Use this short and simple transformation** (both in XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kPersonByVal" match="PersonId" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PersonId[key('kPersonByVal', .)[2]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when the transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<SanctionList>
    <row>
        <PersonId>1000628</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1000634</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1113918</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1133507</PersonId>
        <PersonId>1113918</PersonId>
    </row>
</SanctionList>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<SanctionList>
   <row>
      <PersonId>1000628</PersonId>
      <PersonId>1000634</PersonId>
      <PersonId>1133507</PersonId>
   </row>
</SanctionList>
```

**Explanation**:

1. A wellknown design pattern for copying an existing XML document and deleting/replacing/inserting some nodes into the copy, is by overriding the identity rule.
2. In this particular case the task is to delete `<PersonId>` elements. This is done by providing a matching template with no (empty) body.
3. The criterion for deletion is that the element must have a duplicate -- that is, at least two `<PersonId>` elements must exist, having the same string value. This is most conveniently done using an `<xsl:key>` declaration and the `key()` function to get all elements with the same string value.
4. Finally, in the match pattern of the empty (deleting) template we check if the node-set of equally-valued elements has a second element.

**Note**: You can learn more about the `<xsl:key>` declaration and the `key()` function in module 9 of my Pluralsight training course "**[XSLT 2.0 and 1.0 foundations](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/xslt-foundations-part1/table-of-contents)**"